# Make a circle draggable

Tags: javascript, raphael

Hi there i have created a circle that response to a button nd it changes its position,

```
var dot = paper.circle(300, 330, 5).attr({ "fill" : "black", "stroke-width" : 5, });
var drawDot = function (cy) {
  dot.animate({
    "cy" : cy
  }, 6000, "linear" );
}

var dotState = "dotYes";
buttonElem.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {

  if (dotState === "dotNo"){
    dotState = "dotYes";
    drawDot("325");}
  else {
    dotState = "dotNo"
    drawDot("195") }
});
```

i want the circle to :
"Make the dot draggable
a. Hint: use listeners for mousedown, mouseup, and mousemove events. Create and set a “state” variable (eg ‘draggingDot’) outside of your listener callback functions in order to keep track of the mouse state between mousemove callbacks
b. Hint: listen for mousedown on the dot, but mouseup and mousemove anywhere on the div where the paper lies - this will make sure you don’t “lose” the dot if you crag your mouse too quickly.
c. In the listener for mouse moves, use an ‘if’ statement to check the state of your ‘dragging’ variable."

I have no idea how to update the position  of the mouse with the mousedown listener,

any help or clarity about wt should i do would be appreciated.

tkx

Comment: `function(ev){ ev.screenX; ev.screenY;}` 

You need to update position of the dot based on the current position of the mouse.

ev.screenX is the x-coordinate of the mouse on the screen, ev.screenY is the y-coordinate of the mouse on the screen.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousedown

Comment: well i hv tried                                                              dot.addEventListener("mousedown", function(ev) { ev.screenX; ev.screenY;})   but i can't drag the dot .

Comment: It looks like drawdot is a function that takes in a single y-coordinate, so you may be able to call drawDot(ev.screenY). If you need to have x, I'm guessing you need to update drawDot to take an x-value, too. Then there is probably a cx property you can add to the first parameter of .animate

Comment: It depends if this is homework or not. If not, just do dot.drag() and it will do it all for you :). If it is homework, miir has helped with the initial bit, you then need to look at the mousemove event.

Comment: well wt i need is to make the dot draggable in the CY dimension by mousedown addEventListerer but still is not working. wt i came up with is to update the position by animate fast the dot but not wt  i need to do . here wt i did                                                                                                                      document.getElementById("mySVGCanvas").addEventListener("mousedown", 
         function(ev){

          dot.animate({  
                    "cy" : ev.offsetY                   
                     }, 20, "linear" );
    })

Comment: Do you need to use the `mousedown`, `mousemove` and `mouseup`? Using the RaphaelJS `drag` function would make your life a lot easier?